# How to make a div appear over a background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly here is an image of my design to make it easier to understand:

I am in the process of trying to create the center content which appears over the top of the image, although when I add divs into my html with a background colour just to test where they are, I'm seeing no change from the above image. I'm wondering if perhaps they are appearing below the image or behind it, although I have changed the z-indexes without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Which div do you want over the top of the image?

Comment: @UtkarshBais The wrapper, i gave it a bg coloir of aqua just so i could see its location on the page but nothing appears

Comment: You can try these two things, first give the z-index of the image as -1, just to test and give the z-index of the wrapper as 999, you'll know for sure what is not working. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I ran your html markup, seems like your wrapper is already on top of the home background. I couldn't rectify as I don't have the resources like your image etc.

Comment: @UtkarshBais That's weird, surely it should be a large blue rectangle though right?

Comment: I gave your background red color and the large aqua thing was on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the `div` with the map in it from your first image, then you'll want to do something along the lines of this in your html:

```
<div id='header'>
<img src='...'>
</div>

<div id='floater'>
<div id='floatContent'></div>
</div>
```

Then in your css, something along the lines of:

```
.header{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
.floater{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: not the map, just a general div container which will eventually have things like the map inside it. I just want a div to appear over the image but can't understand why it isn't appearing @GlueDigiStu

Answer (score 0):

I can't really work with the provided code, but I can tell you what you should do. You should add the background image in CSS, then add the div you wish inside the header after the nav, and then position it using CSS on the background image.

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="Menu.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="Burritos.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">Burritos</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">About Us</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">

    </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-image: url(img/your-img.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh; /* or whatever you wish */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px; /* or how much do you want */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggQJpX

Hope I understood correctly what you want.

Comment: I don't want the header to have a background image the header is fine as it is. I want the image to also remain where it is I just can't understand why the wrapper div with aqua colour isn't appearing over the top of it @Radu B

Comment: I've made a simple pen for better understanding: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggQJpX. The gray area is a placeholder for the background image, and the black container is the div, which is on the background image and centered. Of course, the div container can be filled with anything. Isn't that what you're requesting?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an image as background and add absolutely positioned content div placing over background. also set semi transparent background to `.content`

```css
html, body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#Page {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-1.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1280;
    height: 100%;
}

#home-bg {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: -1;
}

header {
    background-color: #1c1c1b;
    font-family: 'Century gothic';
    font-size: 180%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #009641;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.header-image {
    align-content: center;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.scroll {
    height: 80px; 
    font-size: 180%;
}

.header-image-scroll {
    height: 80px;
}

#center-column {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav {

}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*display: inline;*/
    padding: 0 10px;
}

nav li a {
    color: #009641;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #e2030e;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: rgba(180,255,180, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid green;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<body id="chesters">

 
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="Menu.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="Burritos.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">Burritos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html" style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">About Us</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

    <div id="Page">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor amet
          </div>      
        </div>      
    </div> <!-- Page -->

    </body>
```

Comment: Yeah this is closer to what I need thanks, I also just got it to work myself and the problem seems to be having the height of the wrapper set to 100%. If I set a pixel height then the div appears fine and everything works, do you Know why 100% height causes the div to dissapear? Thanks @Banzay

Comment: I think first you need to set dimensions for `html, body`

Comment: maybe one more nested div is redundant but I didn't catch what is wrapper doing.

Comment: Ok i've done that and now it's kind of working, here's a screenshot https://gyazo.com/9d48720313d2890292cb0902f62918a0 as you can see the div is now showing behind the image (image has 80% opacity) however if i change the z-index the wrapper is remaining behind the image. I will update the question with all the updated code @Banzay

Comment: Nope. I remove image tag and made this image as background of `#Page`